# how to pass the instance value from one class the other class containing test annotated method

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Class1**-UIHandler1.java

```
public WebDriver Assettype_dropdown(WebDriver driver,WebElement dropdown,String name) throws InterruptedException {
        wait_until_clickable(driver,dropdown,120);
        dropdown.click();
        search.click();
        search.sendKeys(name);
        insearchesult2.click();
        view_btn.click();
        return driver;
    }

    public WebDriver result_verification(WebDriver driver,String APIR,String msg) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        search_view.sendKeys(APIR);
        assertEquals(driver,table_data,APIR,msg);
        return driver;
    }
```

**Class 2** testng class

```
public class cucumbermain extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
    public static WebDriver driver;
@AfterMethod() //AfterMethod annotation - This method executes after every test execution
         public static void screenShot(ITestContext context){
         //using ITestResult.FAILURE is equals to result.getStatus then it enter into if condition
     if(ITestResult.SUCCESS==result.getStatus()){
         try{

    // To create reference of TakesScreenshot

         TakesScreenshot screenshot=(TakesScreenshot)driver;
         // Call method to capture screenshot
         File src=screenshot.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
     // Copy files to specific location 
         // result.getName() will return name of test case so that screenshot name will be same as test case name
         FileUtils.copyFile(src, new File("D:\\"+result.getName()+".png"));
         System.out.println("Successfully captured a screenshot");
         }catch (Exception e){
             System.out.println("Exception while taking screenshot "+e.getMessage());
         }
         } 
         }
```

**Here I have to pass the driver value returned from **UI Handler1.java** to the **After method** in cucumber main.The driver in UIHandler class is obtained from another test class which holds the test class information
I couldn't store the driver value in the testng After method from another class**

Error Iam geting

> Exception while taking screenshot null
>   Screenshot action entry

Answer (score 0):

To report the results and to take a screenshot on Cucumber project you need to use cucumber hooks and not testng annotations, the way you're using is confusing. [Read more here about hooks.](https://www.baeldung.com/java-cucumber-hooks)

And if you're trying to do something on failure you can create listeners that implement some testng listeners, [try this](https://www.guru99.com/listeners-selenium-webdriver.html).